# Can I control the value of a Moose object when used in a scalar context?

Tags: perl, object, overloading, moose

Is it possible (and sensible) to change the value that a Moose object evaluates to ina scalar context. For example if I do

```
my $object = MyObject->new();
print $object;
```

Instead of printing something like:

```
MyObject=HASH(0x1fe9a64)
```

Can I make it print some other custom string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into the [`overload`](http://p3rl.org/overload) pragma. I don't think you can overload scalar context, but try overloading stringification (which is denoted by `""`, <s>which you must quote becoming the silly looking `'""'`</s>, quoting using the `q` operator make this more readable).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package MyObject;

use Moose;

use overload 
  q("") => sub { return shift->val() };

has 'val' => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'rw', required => 1);

package main;

my $obj = MyObject->new( val => 'Hello' );

print $obj; # Hello
```

Comment: I always think that something like `q("")` is far easier to read as the stringification key.

Comment: be sure to setup your fallback with overloading, so that other operations on the value will still work.

Answer (score 2):

The following may also save you some head scratching:

`use namespace::autoclean;`, which is sometimes mentioned/suggested in relation to Moose, is not compatible with `use overload q("")...`.

Generally what happens is that you drop the `use namespace::autoclean;`, and then the `use overload q("")...` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Have a look at [overloading](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html) `""`.

To decide, if that is sensible is up to you 8)